# chain named_scopes across models ? (ActiveRecord,Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
Class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :modelb
end
Class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :modelc
end
Class ModelC < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :modeld
   named_scope :due_on, lambda {|date| { :conditions => {:due_date => date}}}
end
Class ModelD
   named_scope :has_feature, lambda {|feature| { :conditions => {:feature => feature}}}
end
```

Can i do the following

```
a = ModelA.find(1)

a.modelb.modelc.due_on(today).modeld.has_feature(somefeature).should return_an_array_of_instances_of_ModelD
```

If not, what is the best practice for referencing a related modeld object from an modela object.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to avoid breaking the Demeter law, and create abstractions for it.

i.e. `a.modelb.ending(today).with_feature(feature)`

Nice read about it: http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/